# How can I format url input Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Hey I need to change the format of url when a client inserts an url to the input box. When I fill the input field with a url "www.example.com" an error message appears. The correct format for the url would be "https://www.example.com".

```
  <div>
      <x-jet-label for="website" value="{{ __('main.Website') }}"/>
      <x-jet-input id="website" type="text"
                         wire:model.defer="website" autocomplete="website"/>
   </div>
```

This is the fortify part.

```
  'website' => ['nullable', 'url'],
```

I need to make both of them valid, both with and without the https part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own regex like this:

```
'website' => ['nullable','regex:/[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/i']
```

This is a regex link you can customize it as you need!

[URL regular expression](https://regexr.com/39nr7)

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you, I've been searching all over the internet for this. I'd mark your answer as useful but I don't have enough reputation. Have a nice day bro!

Comment: @LaravelLiwevireQuestion
Don't mention it bro !